# Aurelia: resize/layout change event for view?

Tags: javascript, canvas, aurelia

Is there a way to subscribe to a view in order to observe resize/layout events in Aurelia? I have a canvas I would like to resize. I'm wondering if there is an "aurelia" way to do this?

I tried:

```
<div ref="canvasContainer" class="widget-dial-container" resize.delegate="doresize()">
  <canvas ref="canvas" class="widget-dial-canvas" />
</div>
```

but it never calls my `doresize()` method.

I've tried binding to the DOM offsetWidth and offsetHeight, but this doesn't work either (with and without `@bindable canvasContainer;` in the vm)

Comment: You can't use the resize event on a div

Comment: which is why I'm asking if aurelia has come up with a way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `resize` event is only supported on the `window` itself, as Kruga mentioned. You can attach to it in a cross-platform fashion using the Aurelia Platform Abstraction Layer's `PLATFORM` object.  You'll have to run `jspm install aurelia-pal` to get it. If you aren't worried about cross-plat, then you can just use the `window` object.

The following template and VM work for me. I implemented a throttle on the resize timer:

HTML

```
<template>
  <div style="height: 125px; min-width: 150px; width: 100%;" ref="canvasContainer">
    <canvas ref="canvas" width.one-way="canvasContainer.offsetWidth"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>
```

TEMPLATE

```
import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';

export class App {
  resizeTimer = null;
  resizeEventHandler = () => this.resized();

  attached() {
    this.resized();

    PLATFORM.global.addEventListener("resize", this.resizeEventHandler);
  }

  detached() {
    PLATFORM.global.removeEventListener("resize", this.resizeEventHandler);
  }

  resized() {
    clearTimeout(this.resizeTimer);

    this.resizeTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      let ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

      ctx.fillStyle = "green";
      ctx.font = "30px Arial";
      ctx.fillText(`Width: ${this.canvas.width}`,10,50);
    }, 150);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ashley, do you think you could help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978120/how-can-i-configure-two-or-more-apps-in-aurelia-using-webpack

Comment: I'm not a webpack expert, but I asked our webpack guy to take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

I made an add-on that makes use of a package `npm:element-resize-detector`. This will detect all changes to a div's size, including those from css animations.

https://github.com/MeirionHughes/aurelia-resize

install it:

```
npm install aurelia-resize --save
```

add it to your config:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .plugin('aurelia-resize');
```

add a method on your view-model:

```
foo(detail){
    console.log("width=" + detail.width);
    console.log("height=" + detail.height);
    console.log("old width=" + detail.widthOld);
    console.log("old height=" + detail.heightOld);
}
```

then use it by adding `resizeable` attribute and binding to the resize event.

```
<div resizeable resize.trigger="foo($event.detail)">
```

Comment: Saved the day @merion-hughes.  I had exactly the same issue with a canvas whose container was being set to zero width with show.bind() on a parent. When the div was made visible I needed to resize the canvas.  I could find no way of doing this until I stumbled across this post. Now I call a resize method in response to the container width changing. Thank you.