# How can I configure two or more apps in Aurelia using Webpack

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I'm trying to wrap my head around the starter kit `skeleton-esnext-webpack` and the way the **Aurelia** team has set up the `webpack.config.babel.js`

Now that I have somehow understood how to configure a basic project in Aurelia, before I go any further, what I want to know is whether it is possible to configure more than one app (`aurelia-app`) using Webpack and how?

The ["Quick Start" guide](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/quick-start/1) gave the impression that it is possible by creating more than one js file, each of which should export a `configure` method specifying the root component (`setRoot`). This seemed sort of easy in the "Quick Start" guide, but as it is mentioned it is not optimal for real-world projects, so I need to configure two or more root components using Webpack, the problem is that with all the @easy-webpack stuff thrown everywhere in the configuration file, I honestly don't know where to make the changes.

In the `webpack.config.babel.js` file I can see they're using a ['multiple-entry-point'](http://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html) configuration

```
let config = generateConfig(
  {
    entry: {
      'app': ['./src/main' /* this is filled by the aurelia-webpack-plugin */],
      'aurelia-bootstrap': coreBundles.bootstrap,
      'aurelia': coreBundles.aurelia.filter(pkg => coreBundles.bootstrap.indexOf(pkg) === -1)
    },
    output: {
      path: outDir
    }
  },
```

And then, this is how they use something similar to the `CommonsChunkPlugin`

```
commonChunksOptimize({appChunkName: 'app', firstChunk: 'aurelia-bootstrap'}),
```

But where is the `[name]` entry specified? In fact, where's the appChunckName being specified?

I've been using Webpack for less than a week, I think that it would've been much better to use a "standard" webpack configuration than to use @easy-webpack. Seriously the framework looks great, but just getting started can get really frustrating if you want to use a *"standard"*  configuration.

Comment: Hello @eddy. This should be much simplified with the new skeleton that's coming soon (it's pre-alpha now, hopefully something more usable before the end of the year). It will use a flat-config without the external presets that easy-webpack offers (they'll be optional).

Comment: Looks like Bazyli has gotten back to you. Thanks dude.

Comment: @niieani I see. But please tell me, is it possible to accomplish what I described in my question? I want to use Aurelia in only 2 of the pages of my application and IINM in each of those 2 pages I need to specify an `aurelia-app` attribute pointing to a config file, right? I followed the "Quick Start" guide and everything works fine, but if I want to specify a different root component, something like `aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot("hello"));` I get this error "Uncaught (in promise) Error: (SystemJS) Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) hello.js"

Comment: @eddy I'm not sure how I'd accomplish multi-app setup with the current Webpack setup. It might not be trivial. Why is it that you need multiple separate Aurelia *apps* instead of wrapping their root modules in some sort of a wrapper template?

Comment: @niieani Well seems like another person has asked a question that pretty much described the reason I was trying to configure multiple Aurelia apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029089/is-it-possible-to-use-aurelia-in-a-non-spa-application . Can we use Aurelia for that kind of applications? Or maybe we're trying to use it for something that it wasn't designed for?