# Is it possible to use Aurelia in a non-spa application?

Tags: aurelia, javascript-framework

Recently I've been playing around with different frameworks and libraries, looking for something that really suits my needs.

You see, my job mainly involves creating asp.net mvc applications and for most of them using Razor and a little bit of jQuery is enough. But in certain cases and only for a few pages,which are rarely more than one or two per app, I really need something extra that helps me avoid getting entangled in a bunch of jQuery code.

As I mentioned, I tried a couple of alternatives and from them, the one I liked the most is Aurelia, because of its simplicity and the fact that it embraces standards, BUT the more I dive into the framework, the more I think that it might not be what I'm looking for,as it seems more suitable for full spa applications and what I need is:

- Something that helps me reduce the amount of DOM manipulation
- A efficient templating engine

I know that Aurelia provides that and much more, but I don't want/need a SPA, **I need those functionalities ONLY in some specific pages and not the whole application.**

Can Aurelia help me achieve this? If so, how?

Comment: https://mustache.github.io/

Comment: Have you tried knockout js?  It sounds like that would fit your need pretty well

Comment: I posted a link to working example, and the feature branch in github. Feel free to PM me know if you have any questions about the source code. This is achieving the use case you are asking about. I configured the aurelia-cli setup to strip out all the aurelia components not needed outside of a SPA context.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, Aurelia can help you achieve that. You just won't use certain features like routing in on the pages you create with Aurelia.

That being said, it isn't a drop in replacement for jQuery, but none of the "modern" JS frameworks really are. And you're going to end up spending time learning whichever one you end up choosing.

Check out the `aurelia.enhance` functionality, it might be just what you're looking for!

Comment: Yes certainly routing is the module I don't think I'll need and yes frameworks aren't meant to be a replacement for jQuery, but the use of data binding can help reduce a lot of DOM manipulation code, right? Is there an official link for the functionality you mentioned? I only found a blog post, and I might be wrong, but I don't think I just need to "enhance" some elements of a page, I need to enhance/use Aurelia in the whole page. Is there any resource that shows how to use Aurelia in a non-spa fashion?Do you know if it's been tried before?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Aurelia in a non-SPA context, and it worked out well. I think this is exactly what you describe. For example:

http://legumeinfo.org/chado_phylotree/phytozome_10_2.59028020

https://github.com/legumeinfo/tripal_phylotree/tree/lis_master/theme/js/aurelia

Comment: btw I dont believe I used `aurelia.enhance` I should look into that for future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using aurelia for dynamic elements on some sites. Like comments for example. Page loads fast w/o comments.Then Aurelia kicks in and loads the comments below. Also with some signalR magic the discussion is updated in real time. It is awesome and insanely easy.